# Introducing marginTop in RelativeLayout creates overlapping

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to display information to the user through the use of a `RelativeLayout` but when I use `layout_marginTop` or `paddingTop` to create some spacing betweem my items the item below won't take in into account and they will both start overlapping.

Here are a few pics to help understand my problem :

Initial situation:

[image]

Adding a `android:marginTop="48dip"` to the `TextView` to better illustrate the problem:

[image]

I also tried adding the same `android:marginTop="48dip"` to the `EditText` but the result was unexpected too. (Link to the screenshot can be find in the comment as a user with less than 10 reputation can't post more than 2 links)

The Layout I'm using (simplified version)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">
<!--Identification part-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idPartTV"
            android:text="Site"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/idPartLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/idPartTV"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <!--Site name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/siteNameTV"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idPartLine"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/siteName"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name"
            android:layout_below="@id/idPartLine"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transTV"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/siteNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip" />
    <!--Site ID-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/siteIdTV"
            android:text="ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/siteName" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/siteID"
            local:MvxBind="Text Id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/siteName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/transTV"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/siteIdTV" />
<!--location Part-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locPartTV"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/siteID" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/locPartLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/locPartTV"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />
    <!--Latitude-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latTV"
            android:text="Latitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/locPartLine" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/latitude"
            local:MvxBind="Text Latitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/locPartLine"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/transTV"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/latTV"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    <!--Longitude-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longTV"
            android:text="Longitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/latitude" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/longitude"
            local:MvxBind="Text Longitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/latitude"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/transTV"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/longTV"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the snippet of code above, *transTV* is my largest `TextView`. I'm using it to be sure that all the `EditText` will be vertically aligned. *SiteID* is another `EditText` that is situated above the one presented here. As I had a lot of them I mutilated my code to avoid redundancies.

In my idea of the `android:marginTop` and of the `RelativeLayout`, adding some space between the latitude and the separating line should be taken into account to calculate the position of the longitude as it is set to be below the latitude using `android:layout_below`.

Comment: Adding the `android:marginTop="48dip"` to the `EditText` this time : http://i.stack.imgur.com/oiv6J.png

Comment: Could you show the **complete** layout, please?

Comment: Are you sure it's needed ? As I'm repeating the same pattern several times I feel like its more like flooding my question with unnecessary code.. I'll add the upper part at least, tell me if you need the one below too.

Comment: use LinearLayout vertical instead of Relativelayout. @tperon

Comment: @JigarShekh I used to but I switched to the RelativeLayout to be able to align my EditText vertically using layout_toRightOf